# Perl FastCGI and name colission

Tags: perl, collision, fastcgi

I have Apache serving requests through fcgi perl scripts. 
If I have script A.pl with function create_x() and B.pl with function create_x(), is there possibility there will be function name collision?

Answer (score 1):

First of all in Perl you call them `subroutines`. 
Answering your question. that depends in a lot of variables, are they classes ? Do you include one within the other?

If you have `script A.pl` and `script B.pl` and you don't use include them one within the other then you won't have a problem.

For furhter information about this read [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) and [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

You can also use :

```
perldoc -f <use | require>
```

Comment: Script A.pl: 
sub create_x { print 'X'; } Script B.pl: sub create_x { print 'X'; } The q: Will names collide when FCGI runs both scripts in the same process?

Comment: If they are called by a master and both files are included within the same flow then yes, they will collide.